# format iso 8601 to date(YYYY-MM-DD) using luxon

Tags: javascript, luxon, formatdatetime

How to use **Luxon** to convert date data

api data

`2021-09-05T01:39:33Z`

data conversion results I want

`2021-09-05`

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to look at the [Formatting section of the documentation](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting) to read about `.toISODate()`.

Comment: @Andrew Morton

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
let format = `YYYY-MM-DD`;

let now = new Date();

let result = `${now.getFullYear()}-${(now.getMonth() < 10) ? "0" + now.getMonth() : now.getMonth()}-${(now.getDate() < 10) ? "0" + now.getDate() : now.getDate() }`;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Incidentally, instead of `(now.getMonth() < 10) ? "0" + now.getMonth() : now.getMonth()`, you could use the somewhat shorter `("0" + now.getMonth()).slice(-2)`.